# German umlaut characters in form param resteasy not working

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, resteasy, diacritics

My form

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

My Html header

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Tried both and single as well.

My Resteasy filter

```
 request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

My Method annotation

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED + "; charset=UTF-8")
```

Alter all this settings , my Resteasy service receiving the german characters wrongly for only form post. json request working fine.

Is there any other setting I have to try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

works fine with filter level settings. I didn't restart the server properly while trying these settings.

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Where is this setting and the filter? could you please be more precise. Thanks